# Bad termination after program completes

Tags: c, mpi, mpich

I wrote a MPI program in C to test sending/receiving messages between nodes.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int* argc, char*** argv){
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

  int rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

  int size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  if(size < 2){
    fprintf(stderr, "Must have >2 processes.\n");
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
  }

  int number;
  if(rank == 0){
    number = -1;
    MPI_Send(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }

  else if(rank == 1){
    MPI_Recv(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("Received number %d from process 0.\n", number);
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

When running on 2 machines with one process each, the program provides the correct output:

```
Received number -1 from process 0.
```

But also throws the error:

```
================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 4529 RUNNING AT node0
=   EXIT CODE: 2
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
```

Most resources I've found on bad terminations are dealing with segfaults rather than exit code 2. I've tried adding an MPI_Barrier right before MPI_Finalize, which adds an "assert (!closed) failed" error.

Both nodes are using MPICH 3.1.4 on Raspbian 2015-05-05.

Comment: Unless you compile with `-std=c99`, your `main` function returns some unspecified value (in your case equal to `2`) due to the lack of `return 0;` statement.

Comment: neither the argc nor the argv parameter are used within the code.  This results in the compiler raising two warnings about those unused parameters.  suggest changing the main() statement to 'int main( void )'